# How can I convert a HTTP request to curl?

Tags: http, curl

I'm newbie on this so I would like your help, according to CrazyCall [docs](https://developers.crazycall.com/#retrieve-all-users) I want to test those code examples in terminal using CURL, for example this one:

```
GET /api/v1/users HTTP/1.1
x-api-token: your-secret-api-key
Account: your-account-hash.crazycall.com
Host: api.crazycall.com
```

I tried to convert to curl and execute like this:

```
curl -XGET -H 'x-api-token: mdsRFGRV23XXXXXXX' -H 'Account: lopDOPLSVXXXX.crazycall.com' -H 'Host: api.crazycall.com' /api/v1/users
```

But it shows me a message `<url> malformed`

I also added "Content-type: application/json" header but it's still the same.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepand the protocol and domain (`https://api.crazycall.com`) to your path (`/api/v1/users`):

```
 curl -X GET -H 'x-api-token: mdsRFGRV23XXXXXXX' -H 'Account: lopDOPLSVXXXX.crazycall.com' -H 'Host: api.crazycall.com' https://api.crazycall.com/api/v1/users
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that detail, thanks, it works great!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that I found this tool to do the same : https://tools.chilkat.io/httpToCurl.cshtml